# npm install web3 into Appcelerator Titanium SDK > 6.x

Tags: node.js, titanium, appcelerator, ethereum, web3js

I would like to install `web3` into my mobile App project.

However I am having issues with accessing it without having a buch of red screens saying I can't access these files within it. I tried to manually update the paths etc;

What I've done is in my App folder: `npm install web3`

Then I see the `node_modules` folder in my App directory... however, I am not able to require the module in my index.js file with a simple:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); // throws error
var web3 = new Web3();

function doClick(e) {
    var version = web3.version.api;
    $.label.text = "Web3 version: " + version;
}

$.index.open();
```

Now I've pasted the folder from the `node_modules` into a `lib` I created under App folder, and tried to access the `dist` within that to access `web3.min`, then tried a whole lot of other things, with no luck... has anybody else had such issue or have a solution?

Comment: Added a Jira issue at Appc for what it's worth: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module isn't going to work. From the Appc Node.js Support doc under [minor differences](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Node.js_Support-section-src-48431321_Node.jsSupport-Minordifferences):

> SDK doesn't have replacements for Node's core modules

I think this actually a major difference, as many node modules or their dependencies use Node.js core modules.  For example, `web3` uses a module called `XMLHttpRequest`, which in turn uses the Node.js core [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module.  Titanium will throw an error saying it 'couldn't find module: url for architecture: x86_64'.  There are most likely several other core module dependencies.

The Node.js support, at least currently, appears to be best suited for standalone js libraries.  Think `momentjs` or `underscore` (though those are already built-in to Alloy).

Comment: Thanks Adam for this info.