# Install npm packages in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

According to the docs, Titanium now has support to install npm packages: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Node.js_Support

However, upon reading it, I am very confused as to where to actually put my `node_modules` directory. There is some mention in the docs about a `Resources` directory, however, for Alloy this is supposed to be left empty, as it is frequently overwritten by the compiler.

So my question is, where do I put my `node_modules` and how do I reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experimentation, it seems like you can do `npm install` in the `app/lib/` so your package are in `app/lib/node_modules`. This does NOT work on the `app/` directory.

Note that if you use `tishadow`, you will also need to install the npm packages there as well in the `Resources/` directory (as they still do not use the Alloy framework).

Answer (score 1):

In Alloy project you are supposed to run `npm install` inside the `app` folder. But according to this bug [JIRA Ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5077) modules that use core-modules won't work correctly. So you have to try if you module works.

Another explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45041737/5193915